# Problemas de conexión a mysql

Tags: mysql

Desde php estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos:

Este es mi código:

```
if(!($iden = mysql_connect("gator4208.hostgator.com", "akyna_admin", "XXXXXX"))) 
die("Error: No se pudo conectar");
```

El nombre de usuario `akyna_admin` y la clave están bien, además tiene todos los privilegios.

Pero obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'akyna_admin'@'gator4208.hostgator.com' (using password: YES) in /home1/akyna/public_html/php.php on line 37
>   Error: No se pudo conectar

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Es una conexión remota?

Comment: Gracias igual. Ya capte yo misma el error al escribir, tenía que poner localhost en lugar del ftp del server. Espero sirva para quienes escriban lo mismo que yo. Saludos.

Comment: No Shaz, estaba en el mismo server y yo llamando a un remoto :(. Terrible, pero sirve supongo para ayudar a otros, de que no lo estaba llamando remoto.

Comment: Agrega tu solución en una respuesta (y acéptala) con una buena descripción, para que le pueda servir a otras personas en el futuro.

Comment: Hola @Akyna como sugerencia, no uses  MYSQL como driver para la conexion, usa en su lugar mysqli o PDO, ya que las funciones de MYSQL quedaron obsoletas en PHP 5.5 y se eliminaron en PHP 7.

Comment: Si eso estoy viendo...que mysqli está más fácil y actualizado! Gracias!!!

Comment: Hola Akyna. Apoyo la indicación de @Shaz. Por favor publica una respuesta al problema y luego de un par de días la aceptas.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un problema de sintaxis, te falta el `or` al final del condicional.

```
if(!($iden = mysql_connect("gator4208.hostgator.com", "akyna_admin", "XXXXXX")))
```

`or`  `die("Error: No se pudo conectar");`

Sino prueba de hacerlo sin el condicional.

```
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error()); echo 'Connected successfully';
```

http://php.net/manual/es/mysql.examples-basic.php

[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)